# Tail event? Existence of a limit of RVs

Tags: probability, limits

**Question:**
$X_1, X_2 ...$ are independent RVs, such that $X_i\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ for all $i$.
The event $A$ is defined as $$A=\left\{ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {X_1+...+X_n}{n}  \text{exists}\right\}.$$
Find $E(X_1|A)$.

**Thoughts**:
I know that $$E[X_1|A]=\frac {E[X_1\chi_A]}{P(A)}.$$ I need a hint on calculating $P(A)$. I've gotten a hint that it's related to it being a tail event. I'd love to get an intuition how to prove it is such.

Thanks

Comment: What about the definition? What do you have to prove in order to show that $A$ is a tail event?

Comment: It seems like all you need to do is invoke the law of large numbers, and the problem becomes trivial. Is that not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the strong law of large numbers,
$$\mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = 1\right)=1. $$
It follows that $\mathbb P(A)=1$, and hence $\mathbb E[X_1|A]=\mathbb E[X_1]=1$.

To explicitly show that $A$ is a tail event, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then $S_n\geqslant 0$ almost surely, so it suffices to show that
$$B=\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1n S_n <\infty\right\} $$
is a tail event. For any $m$, we have
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1n S_n =\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1n(S_n-S_m), $$
since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n S_m=0.$$
For any $n>m$,
$$S_n-S_m=\sum_{i=m+1}^n X_i\in\sigma(X_{m+1}, X_{m+2}, \ldots). $$
It follows that $B$ is a tail event.